# Joomla, gantry template. Page not showing correct sidebar

Tags: php, joomla2.5

Using Joomsef, Joomla! 2.5.14 and Gantry template. We've done a rather large website however there one page which isn't displaying the sidebar at all

http://www.flomatik.co.uk/engineering-services as you can see here this is the page with the issues.

http://www.flomatik.co.uk/fes-facilities This is the one working correctly. They both side the same module for the side bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

Where clients had made this page before Joomsef saved the old menu ID to the sef area. Due to this different menu IDs were being used and this created the problem. Once the menu ID was changed in the SEF the module worked correctly.